# Unable to add object to Class

Tags: java, class, object

relatively new to Java but I have written a few projects in Java and I've never had an issue before adding objects to a class. I get a null pointer exception when it tries to add the object.

Apologies in advance if it's a really stupid question but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Main Class

```
public class Patience {

private Deck deck;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        game.testFunc();
        }


    public void testFunc(){

        Deck testBlackCard = new BlackCard("2", "c");
        System.out.println(testBlackCard.getRank());
        deck.add(testBlackCard);
        Deck testRedCard = new RedCard("5", "b");
        deck.add(testRedCard);

    }
```

Super Class (Holds both red and black cards)

```
public class Deck{

public String rank;
public String suit;


    public Deck(String rankOfCard, String suitOfCard){
        this.rank = rankOfCard;
        this.suit = suitOfCard;
    }

    public String getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }

    public String getRank(){
        return rank;
    }

    public void add(Deck testCard) {
        this.add(testCard);         
    }


public class BlackCard extends Deck{
```

Below is the BlackCard Class

```
public class BlackCard extends Deck{
    public BlackCard(String rank, String suit){
        super(rank, suit);
    }
```

Comment: which line throws the exception ?

Comment: where is the error being thrown? which object is causing this?

Comment: I never see you define `game` anywhere.. `game.testFunc();`

Comment: your `Deck#add()` method calls itself. Is it your actual intention? I think `StackOverflowError` is more likely to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick tip, you might want to call your Deck class Card instead, since it seems to describe the base for a card as opposed to a container of cards (as one might describe a deck)

To actually add the card, you call the add method of deck, but it looks like your add method just calls itself creating an infinite recursion. You'll actually need to be storing the card objects somewhere, probably an ArrayList of cards

To solve this problem, try making your general card class seperate from your deck class. Here's an example class structure to follow:

```
Card -> BlackCard/RedCard (contains methods like getSuit and getRank)

ArrayList -> Deck (contains methods like add, draw, getCards, shuffle)
```

Also, I recommend using enumerators to represent your ranks and suits instead of Strings, but it's not necessary to just get the program working. Maybe try applying the lessons [in this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) after you finish as an extra learning opportinuty

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a new instance of deck first before calling deck.add()...
So you probably want something like `private Deck deck = new Deck();` inside your patience class, and then call `deck.add()` ...